# Cache not clearing when testing on localhost mac os x

Tags: macos, caching, localhost, assetic, symfony

I have a very bizarre error occurring with my symfony 3 project.  After doing some research I've narrowed down the error to being something to do with my system wide cache.

### Why its not symfony related...

I will explain why, but before you think its something else to do with symfony or assetic cache issues read below:

I run the following shell script every-time I deploy to make sure everything is clean for production and dev environment.

```
chown -R distribution:distribution .
rm -rf var/cache/dev/*
rm -rf var/cache/prod/*
rm -rf web/css/*
rm -rf web/js/*
bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
bin/console assets:install web --symlink
bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev
bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql --env=prod
chown -R distribution:distribution .
bin/console server:run
```

I test the dev environment by going to localhost on my computer through an SSH Tunnel.

```
sudo ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -L 80:127.0.0.1:80 -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 -p 25000 fake_super_user_name@(server ip address here)
```

The symfony development version I can access at anytime by going to my browser now and typing localhost:8000

Everything was working up until I did some major changes regarding adding a bundle in and changing the names of routes and files and there locations etc...

### Why its system related...

In google chrome when I go to my page and open up the inspector, I can see its trying to access a file compiled-js_part_1_admin_1.js.  This is an older version of the javascript file I had.  However when I go to the server and look in my FTP program and via console with `ls -al` in the web/js directory that file does not exist! The correct file is compiled-js_part_2_admin_1.js, but the file referenced is in no way on my server.  Therefore its grabbing a cached copy from somewhere on my computer.

[image]

[image]

### So delete the cache in my browser...

This works for my production site at the actual domain name but for some reason when I try to delete the cache with localhost or entirely from Google Chrome nothing seems to delete and it keeps referencing the old file.  I can see this in the cache still also by typing `about:cache` in the url in chrome.  If you are curious how I attempted to delete cache, I open the inspector and hold down on the refresh button and select 'empty cache and hard reload'.

[image]

### Okay so use another browser...

I used Firefox, Safari, and even Opera and all of them even when I have never used that browser before still are requesting the old file when I access via localhost...

I'm guessing its stored in some kind of super cache because its localhost... I have no idea where this is cache is on the system and how to remove it.

In case it matters here is my .htaccess file on the server which does set expiration and caching rules for the files... I was actually trying to test this so I didn't want to disable it, but I'm sure this is the reason its caching, I just want to figure out how to clear cache for localhost so I can develop again knowing I'm seeing the right assets.

**.htaccess**

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# These rules need to be at the bottom!
# Make it aware of True Type Fonts for Web Fonts.
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf

Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag 

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/js "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

### Short Version

If I'm missing any information needed to solve this let me know and I'll post it right away.  Short story, somehow my local system is storing cache that I can not delete. How do I delete this cache that is particular to localhost across all browsers?

Comment: Just as a test, did you tryed to remove manually your bin/cache files, and check if you still got your issue? Also, did you checked if you got assetics compiling your css/js file into one, which may be outdated? (cause you're testing in dev env, right?)

Comment: I'm currently having the issue in both enviroments.  I recently seemed to have fixed the error by doing a cache-busting technique with assetic, but still bothers me that this is possible.  I can re-create this scenario to see if I can figure out if that changes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution...but only sort of.  Assetic was giving a real error, and fixing that error made the cache start to fix it's self.

None the less, this was very strange cache behavior in this scenario.